# kill rate of insecticide differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

A field of wheat teeming with grasshoppers is dusted with an insecticide having a kill rate of 200 per 100 per hour.What percentage of the grasshoppers are still alive 1 hour later?
I did not understand the units.What does 200 per 100 per hour means?Hence I could not solve the problem.answer is 13.53%. Please tell how.

Comment: Are you sure this contains all the information about the problem? If the insecticide kills 200 of 100 grashoppers over an hour, then there are no grasshoppers left after an hour. But your answer seems to imply that there are. So maybe the grasshoppers are reproducing in the meantime to compensate the effect of the insecticide or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means exponential decay, $P(t)=P(0)e^{-2t}$. Fairly standard terminology, though a little peculiar. The $200$ per $100$ is $200\%$.